# Receive invalid credentials (49)when trying to add a user to LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

My ldap.conf looks like:  (server and client on the same machine)

```
# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
BASE    dc=hdlldaptest,dc=net
URI     ldap://localhost
```

Results of ldapsearch -x:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=hdlldaptest,dc=net> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# hdlldaptest.net
dn: dc=hdlldaptest,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: qatest
dc: hdlldaptest

# admin, hdlldaptest.net
dn: cn=admin,dc=hdlldaptest,dc=net
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
```

I try to add a user using this file: qa_test.ldif

```
dn: uid=qa_test,ou=users,dc=hdlldaptest,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: qa_test
uid: qa_test
uidNumber: 16859
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/qa_test
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: qa_test
userPassword: {crypt}x
shadowLastChange: 0
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
```

Then I run

```
# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=ramesh,dc=tgs,dc=com" -f qa_test.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
```

I don't know what password I am supposed to use, I tried leaving as is and entering x. Adding a real password, but every time I run, I get invalid credentials.  I thought that you add the password after the user was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-D` option is used for binding (which account is used to perform the operation), so you need to provide a DN corresponding to a user with sufficient permissions to achieve the  `ldapadd`.

Usually that kind of operations are performed by the LDAP admin/manager, probably `cn=admin,dc=hdlldaptest,dc=net` in your case.

If your directory supports it, you can also bind using [`SASL`](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html) mechanism, for example 'EXTERNAL' (usually TLS or Unix IPC) :

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f qa_test.ldif
```